# I want to make binding to a button style from another button style

Tags: wpf, data-binding, button, styles

I need to make some kind of minding between two buttons. I need that they always have the same style.. I know I can change the fontsize of a word when sliding a slider.. now I need to apply something like that but with the style of the buttons.
I'm looking something on XAML for not to do it through C# if possible!

Comment: What makes your Button's style change? Usually to make both button's share a style, you create one style and set it on each button's `Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"` Perhaps you can make whatever modifies your button properties change the source style instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind two button in two way mode.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="btnStyle1">
            <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="btnStyleTriggers">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Name="btn1" Content="Text" Style="{Binding ElementName=btn2, Path=Style, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Button Name="btn2" Content="Text"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

When one of the buttons style property changes the others style will follow it.